# SQL Case statement combine two fields together?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, case

I have a question about CASE statement. My case statement looks like this:

```
CASE myField1
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Jump'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Sleep'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Eat'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Run'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Break'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Move'
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Stop'
        ELSE NULL END AS TestColumn,
```

On this statement I have to add one more initial based on the value from other field. So on the end of each WHEN options there might be a letter A if myField2 is equal to 1. If not then I will not put the letter A. Output should be something like this:

```
Jump A
Sleep
Eat A
Run
Break
Move A
Stop
```

How I can check for my second field in SQL CASE and concat the value on existing words? If anyone can help please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Simply concat another CASE: `|| CASE WHEN Field2 = '1' THEN ' A' ELSE '' END`

Comment: @dnoeth well, `+` not `||` in SQL Server.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I should know, but I'm used to Standard SQL :-)  (and I overlooked the SS2008 tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just concatenate them together:

```
SELECT (CASE myField1
            WHEN 1 THEN 'Jump'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Sleep'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Eat'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'Run'
            WHEN 5 THEN 'Break'
            WHEN 6 THEN 'Move'
            WHEN 7 THEN 'Stop'
            ELSE ''
       END) + (CASE WHEN myField2 = 1 THEN 'A' ELSE '' END) AS TestColumn,
```

Note:  I changed the `ELSE NULL` to `ELSE ''`.  This allows an `'A'` to appear when the previous value would have no value.  If either argument to `+` is `NULL`, then the result is `NULL`.

On closer inspection, you want a space before the "A".  If you also want "A" when the existing value is absent, use `LTRIM()`:

```
SELECT LTRIM((CASE myField1
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Jump'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'Sleep'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'Eat'
                WHEN 4 THEN 'Run'
                WHEN 5 THEN 'Break'
                WHEN 6 THEN 'Move'
                WHEN 7 THEN 'Stop'
                ELSE ''
           END) +
          (CASE WHEN myField2 = 1 THEN ' A' ELSE '' END)
         ) AS TestColumn,
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for. I haven't combined more than one CASE before. This might be helpful in the future.